# Custom Annotation with @StringDef for String array

Tags: java, android, annotations

i have the following code:

```
public static final String MY_CONSTANT_A = "A";
public static final String MY_CONSTANT_B = "B";

@StringDef(value={
        MY_CONSTANT_A,
        MY_CONSTANT_B
})
private @interface MyAnnotation{}

public static void someFunc(@MyAnnotation String str){

}
```

now when im trying to use string inside someFunc i got the next lint error as excepted:

[image]

now when i change my function to String ... str im not getting this lint error anymore.

```
public static void someFunc(@MyAnnotation String... str){

}
```

[image]

what is the way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no `Support annotation` for Varargs and neither does `StringDef` does this. `StringDef` is just for `String` data type and does not extend to Varargs, yet.

The documentation has nothing on supporting Varargs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/StringDef.html